# Check if Type<T> extends a specific class

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular/TypeScript, how to check at runtime whether a type represented by a [`Type<T>`](https://angular.io/api/core/Type) extends some specific class `BaseClass`?

For instance, suppose we used [`ApplicationRef.componentTypes`](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#componentTypes) to obtain a `Type<any>[]`. Now, we want to iterate through it and check whether a current `Type<any>` extends some `BaseClass`:

```
const types: Type<any>[] = this.applicationRef.componentTypes;

this.navigationComponents = types.filter((type: Type<any>) => {
    // Here we need check whether type extends BaseClass
});
```

What should be the code for the check above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way prototypal inheritance works, you can use `prototype` and `instanceof` to determine whether or not it extends `BaseClass`:

```
types.filter((type: Type<any>) => type.prototype instanceof BaseClass);
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! If I'm not mistaken, it would work only if `BaseClass` is a class and would not if it's an interface? There is no way to make it work with interfaces.

Comment: Yes, it has to be a class, but only constructors can be assigned to `Type<T>`. Anyway, interfaces simply don't exist at runtime, as the type system is erased.